# Powershell azure - Importing csv file into appsettings

Tags: powershell, azure, import, appsettings

Does anyone know how to import a csv file into Azure app settings using powershell?

This is what I currently have but does not work.

```
Function Import-AppSettings 
{
Step-TimeBlock {  

    $csv = "C:\appsettings.csv"
    $appSettingsList = Import-Csv $csv -Encoding UTF8 -Delimiter '|'

    $appSettingsHash = @{}
    Write-Host "current app settings" -foreground yellow;
    ForEach ($kvp in $appSettingsList) {
        $appSettingsHash[$kvp.Name] = $kvp.Value
        write-host $kvp.Name ": " $kvp.Value -foreground green;
    }

    Set-AzureRMWebApp -ResourceGroupName myresourcegroup -Name mywebapp -AppSettings $appSettingsHash
}
}
```

Comment: You need add `Set-AzureRmWebApp` inside Foreach loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need move `Set-AzureRmWebApp` to Foreach loop.

The following script works for me.

```
$csv = "d:\webapp.csv"
$appSettingsList = Import-Csv $csv 

$appSettingsHash = @{}
Write-Host "current app settings" -foreground yellow;
ForEach ($kvp in $appSettingsList) {
    $appSettingsHash[$kvp.Name] = $kvp.Value
    write-host $kvp.Name ": " $kvp.Value -foreground green;
    Set-AzureRMWebApp -ResourceGroupName shuiweb -Name shuiweb -AppSettings $appSettingsHash
}
```

My csv file like below:

```
Name,Value
shuivnet1,shuitest1
shuivnet3,shuitest2
```

Note: If I use `-Encoding UTF8 -Delimiter '|'`, your script does not work. For test, I suggest you could get one `$appSettingHash` and check your hash value. Like below:

```
$appSettingsHash[$appSettingsList.Name[0]]=$appSettingsList.Value[0] 
$appSettingsHash
```

The value should like below:

```
PS C:\Users\v-shshui> $appSettingsHash

Name                           Value
----                           -----
shuivnet1                      shuitest1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Walter. That definitely worked for me. Excellent stuff

Comment: @shui-shengbao for some reason, I ran your script and all my existing App Settings got wiped away, ideas?